# How to hide certain fonts from specific applications?

Tags: kubuntu, fonts

I need to run outdated software (Xilinx ISE) on my computer with Kubuntu 20.04, but the ISE segfaults while loading the Noto fonts at `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto` (found with `strace`).  The software starts fine when I remove that folder, but Noto is Kubuntu's default font.  Some applications are broken, even after changing the default font settings.

Is there a way to hide that folder from outdated software?  Is there any standard and simple solution for my problem?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "my Kubuntu did not like that too much"? Does strace tell you which noto fonts are the problem? Maybe you don't need something like `fonts-noto-cjk`?

Comment: The noto font is kubuntu's default font. I tried changing it in system setting to something elese before deleting it, but some applications were still broken. The font it dies at is "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSans-Regular.ttf" - at least its the last it loads before crashing.

Answer (score 1):

You can **create a new user with appropriate settings** to hide/show resources, including fonts.

1. Create a new user, using your method of choice. `man useradd` should be helpful.
2. Create the file `/home/new-user/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/00-reject-noto.conf` with the following contents:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "/etc/fonts/conf.d/fonts.dtd">
    <fontconfig>

    <selectfont>
       <rejectfont>
          <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto</glob>
          <glob>/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto</glob>
       </rejectfont>
    </selectfont>

    </fontconfig>
   ```
3. Create other font configuration files as desired.
4. If you need to make specific fonts available to the application, you can place them in `/home/new-user/.local/share/fonts/` (or `/home/new-user/.fonts/`, but this location is deprecated).
5. Test that the fonts are hidden: `sudo -H -u [new-user] fc-list | grep -i noto`
6. Run the program: `sudo -H -u [new-user] [command]`

**Notes:**

- If you don't need the Noto fonts to be available for your current user, you can skip the new-user creation step and just apply the settings to your current home directory.
- If you want to hide specific fonts, you can use `<pattern>` instead of `<glob>` in the font configuration:

  ```
   <rejectfont>
       <pattern><patelt name="family"><string>Noto Kufi Arabic</string></patelt></pattern>
   </rejectfont>
  ```
- For a list of font names, you can use a command similar to the following:

  ```
   fc-list | grep -i noto | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/^\ //g ; s/,/\n/g' | sort -u
  ```

**See Also:**

- Archwiki: [Users and groups](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_groups).
- ArchWiki: [Font Configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_Configuration)

Comment: Thanks for that! I was also really annoyed by all the literal hundreds of Noto variants. I originally uninstalled `fonts-noto-extra`, but then the "dots" when entering a password on the lock screen were misaligned (they were clearly from one of the "extra" fonts), so I reinstalled it and ended up filtering out all but a few generic Noto variants. Ended up with 165 globs in the config file :rolling_eyes:

Comment: Too bad there isn't a way (that I know of) to collapse them all under one font name.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove noto-mono entirely or hide it from certain applications. You only have to downgrade it a little bit.

What worked out for me was

1. Delete current noto font folder in your Kubuntu 20.04 installation.
2. Get a copy of noto fonts from kubuntu 18.04 ISO or installation.
3. Place that older version of noto folder where newer version used to be.

You can also download the kubuntu18.04 version of noto from here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kadGq6BGOyncoArN6Xqm1srJnFR8c0hK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: 1. It's usually not a good idea to directly modify system files this way. The files can be changed by the package manager at any time, recreating the problem, and requiring the user to rediagnose the issue. 2. Rather than provide a link to a personal archive, which you could withdraw at any time, it's better to link to the appropriate [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=noto&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all) and provide instructions to install and freeze versions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I will soon update my answer according to the aforementioned points.